# VBA open excel workbook based on first part of file name?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open an excel workbook using vba:

```
'Open Planner
On Error Resume Next
Set WB = Workbooks("(FILE NAME).xlsx")
On Error GoTo 0
If WB Is Nothing Then 'open workbook if not open
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open("G:\BUYING\Food Specials\6. Depot Memos\" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("T8").value & "\(File Name).xlsx", Password:="samples", WriteResPassword:="samples", UpdateLinks:=False)
End If
```

The problem i have is my file changes name from time to time like so:

```
Depot Memo 12 - 13
Depot Memo 13 - 14
Depot Memo 15 - 16
```

How can i open the file based on the first part of its filename 'Depot Memo'?
I'm brand new to VBA so i'd really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you know the file name to be opened at the time the macro runs? If no, what's the criteria to search for it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this example based on answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41282036/vba-open-file-with-wildcard-knowing-only-extension) (Shout-out to @Alex K.):

Just replace your code part like this:

```
'Open Planner
'This is your routine here
On Error Resume Next
Set WB = Workbooks("(FILE NAME).xlsx")
On Error GoTo 0
If WB Is Nothing Then 'open workbook if not open
    Set WB = FindDepotMemo
End If
'and there you need another check if WB is nothing
```

And add this function to your project:

```
Function FindDepotMemo() As Workbook
    Dim Path As String
    Dim FindFirstFile As String

    Path = "G:\BUYING\Food Specials\6. Depot Memos\" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("T8").Value & "\"

    FindFirstFile = Dir$(Path & "Depot Memo*.xlsm")

    If (FindFirstFile <> vbNullString) Then
        Set FindDepotMemo = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & FindFirstFile, Password:="samples", WriteResPassword:="samples", UpdateLinks:=False)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: does this code include setting the workbook to depot memo if it is already open though and if not already open then open it? I can see this code giving an error if the workbook is already open. How would i keep my check if the workbook is open section of my code with this?

Comment: @user7415328, I updated answer to fit in your routine, feel free to add checks and errorhandling!

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but i don't think this works. I get an object undefined error for WB. I removed the line Set WB = Workbooks("(FILE NAME).xlsx") since i do not have a file called file name, and the set WB = FinDepotMemo should be the name of the workbook instead. But i'm still getting the error

Comment: @user7415328, error about already opened workbook or what? It's OK that WB can be nothing while your Depot Memo* workbook is opened (e.g., after error, your WB is local vaiable). Just check for that case too with iterating over opened workbooks.